# Не выполняется в SQL скриптe UTL_RECOMP.recomp_parallel

Tags: oracle, plsql

Не выполняется в SQL скрипте следующая часть кода:

```
declare

v_res number;
begin
...
...
...
execute immediate 'begin UTL_RECOMP.recomp_parallel(4); end;';
...
```

Ошибка:

```
Error report:
ORA-06550: Строка 1, столбец 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'begin UTL_RECOM.recomp_parallel must be declared
ORA-06550: Строка 1, столбец 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06512: на line 120
```

Выполняю с dba правами.

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно сообщение об ошибке - `'begin UTL_RECOM.recomp_parallel`. Такого идентифера действительно нет. вставте `null;` вместо пакета, с большей долей вероятности ошибка повторится.

Answer (score 2):

Прав `dba` явно недостаточно для выполнениния скрипта.
Убедитесь, что он выполняется в соответствии с [UTL_RECOMP Operational Notes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/UTL_RECOMP.html#GUID-F9528CA0-F71D-44CE-9A0F-39FE8E0868B8):

> - This package **must be run using** SQL*PLUS.
> - You **must be connected** AS SYSDBA to run this script.

---

Самый первый шаг для диагностирования подобных ошибок, создайте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример (mcve)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Для примера как в вопросе это всего лишь одна строка:

```sql
SQL> exec UTL_RECOMP.recomp_parallel(4)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

> Выполняю с dba правами.

А это точно анонимный блок, а не скомпилированный кусок кода? В скомпилированном роли по-умолчанию не работают.

И попробуйте вызов с явным указанием схемы.

```
sys.utl_recomp.recomp_parallel
```

Answer (score 0):

Сообщение об ошибке не соответствует примеру (одной буквы не хватает):

> UTL_RECOM.recomp_parallel

а в примере все правильно: UTL_RECOMP.recomp_parallel. 
Проверте написание, саму процедуру я проверил, всё работает